# Parallax scrolling, Loop script for each class

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, parallax

i'm new to the whole building themes thing and i struggle with a piece of code.

Here is the problem.
everything works and load correctly except that the parallax images don't scroll as they should.
I would like the scroll effect to be reset for each of the target ID because now only the first image scroll and the rest is fixed.

So if im correct i need to somehow reset the images position for each div.

I'm thankfull for your help.

Best / Fredrik

HTML Markup:

```
<div class="parallaxbox" id="pb" style="background-image: url('');">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
function parallax() {
    setpos("#pb");
}



function setpos(element, factor) {
    factor = factor || 1.5;

    var offset = $(element).offset();
    var w = $(window);

    var posx = (offset.left - w.scrollLeft()) / factor;
    var posy = (offset.top - w.scrollTop()) / factor;

    $(element).css('background-position', '100% '+posy+'px');

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    parallax();
}).scroll(function () {
    parallax();
});
```

CSS:

```
.parallaxbox {
    position: relative;
    background: #444;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like the problem is with your jQuery selector. You are using the ID selector `$("#pb")` which will only return the first element it finds in the DOM with the ID of 'pb', which would explain why the parallax effect is not being applied to the other elements.

If you need to match multiple elements you should use jQuery's class selector, like so:

```
function parallax() {
    setpos(".parallaxbox");
}
```

Working example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v79boeu8/1/)